# Backbone: Use Model's Data and Functions in View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, model, coffeescript

I'm fairly new to Backbone and was wondering how to access a model's data and functions from a view that injects the model as a dependency.

My model looks like this:

**countries.coffee**

```
define [
  'underscore'
  'backbone'
  'parse'
], (_, Backbone, Parse) ->
  'use strict';

  class CountriesModel extends Parse.Object

    countries: ['GB','US','FR','JP','WL','ZM','NG']

    returnCode = (code) ->
      return code
```

And my view looks like this:

**country.coffee**

```
define [
  'jquery'
  'underscore'
  'backbone'
  'templates'
  'models/projects'
  'models/countries'
], ($, _, Backbone, JST, CountriesModel, ProjectModel) ->
  class CountryView extends Backbone.View

    ...

    console.log countries

    returnCode(4)
```

I'm injecting the `CountriesModel` as a dependency, but when I call the function or log the `countries` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: returnCode is not defined
```

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I’ve updated the code above to provide a bit more context.

I’m trying to create a re-usable model (`CountriesModel`), so I can access that `countries` array and the `returnCode` function on different views across my app. But I  can’t work out how to access them on my `CountryView`.

My `CountryView` is already requiring a model `ProjectModel`, and I’m able to call functions and arrays from `ProjectModel` like this:

this.model.exampleArray
 this.model.exampleFunction()

I can’t work out how I call functions or arrays from my `CountriesModel`.

Anyone know what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "injecting" do you mean you are requiring in the model and instantiating it in the view? This is ok practice and you would be able to access whatever you want on it. You haven't showed the important part of the code so I cannot see what you did wrong

Comment: @DominicTobias Sorry, I meant requiring and instantiating like you said. I’ve updated the code to provide a bit more context.

Comment: I think you need to change the order of your dependencies in the example, should be: `($, _, Backbone, JST, ProjectModel, CountriesModel)`.

Comment: what does your models/projects look like? as @SergeyDenisov points out, your require statements are reversed.Whats more important here though is how you instantiated the objects, adding dependencies in a require statement doesnt mean it will be used. show the constructor code and the objet instantiation code with the arguments passed in

Comment: recommend taking a look at Marionette. extends Backbone and makes reusing models a breeze. Not too sure why you're injecting instead of including the model with the View constructor; use a Controller one level higher to hold the common model and create the different views

Answer (score 4):

I think that in this particular case, it would be useful for you to create a model "countryModel" and a backbone collection "countriesCollection". But that might not be the nature of your question (your update indicates that you struggle with reusability of the model) so I won't take that into account in my answer.
I don't know coffeescript, but I'll elaborate using Javascript.
The answer is indeed technically to pass models via the `options` parameter to the view during instantiation.

I think that it is overall a good idea to use presenter objects to manage specific views groups. This object would instantiate views that are related, and as you mentioned it, allow injecting an instance of the countriesModel into this presenter.
Imagine hypothetically that you have a webapp that renders a map and list with places that require the model you describe for some reason. You could have code that looks like this:

```
var countriesModel = new CountriesModel(); 

var headerPresenter = new HeaderPresenter(); 
var mapPresenter = new MapPresenter(countriesModel); 
var listPresenter = new ListPresenter(countriesModel);
```

What happens is that you instantiate the model only once, and inject the instance into the presenters that require it.
In the presenter object you can immediately access the properties / methods set on the passed model.

This approach allows you to quickly identify which presenters require the re-usable model.
Should you require the component in new presenters as well, it is easy to pass it in.
Then, within the presenter you can still choose to which views specifically you want to send the model.

Eg. list presenter:

```
function listPresenter(countriesModel){ 
    this.listView = new ListView({ "model": countriesModel); 
    //More views can be added with the same model instance 
};
```

Either from within the views or the presenters, you are able to listen to events on the model, execute its methods and re-render the views.
Personally I manage this logic from the presenter, because this is the place where I use other injected services and components to perform eg. server calls or specific calculations that might be common for different views. Handling this common logic for different views is easily done by passing an event aggregator to each of the view instances. The views trigger custom events to do what is required and the presenter listens to custom events, executes the required logic and (re-)renders views.
I prefer to keep the view clean and focused on DOM interaction / DOM event binding.

**Sidenote**: Backbone Marionette offers an app level event aggregator, which saves you the pain of passing in event aggregators to every view individually.
It is also a very convenient lib to render views from the presenter by using syntax like:

```
var someView = new SomeView(); 
var region = new Marionette.Region({ el: "#some-region" }); 
region.show(someView);
```

Re-showing views by using Marionette regions is memory-safe.

Hopefully this is of any help.

Answer (score 3):

TBH I don't really get why you are using your model as a deps. A good view should abstract from the model and the model should be attached to the view from the route.

```
// this goes in your view file
var CountryView = Backbone.view.extend({
    // here goes all the view logic to display the model data
    // you can refer to your model using this.model
})

...
// in the router file
var myModel = new CountriesModel();

var router = Backbone.router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": home,
        "home": home
    },
    home: function (){
       var view = new CountryView({ model: myModel});
       view.render(); //if you didn't rendered the view in the initialize method
    }
})
```

---

You can access another model in the view attaching it at runtime in the router

```
...
// in the router file
var myModel = new CountriesModel();
var anotherModel = new ProjectModel();


var router = Backbone.router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": home,
        "home": home
    },
    home: function (){
       var view = new CountryView({
                               model: myModel
                               anotherModel: anotherModel
                               });
       view.render(); //if you didn't rendered the view in the initialize method
    }
})
```

and in CountryView attach it in the initialize function

```
initialize: function (options){
    this = _.extend(options, this)
    // or
    // this.anotherModel = options.anotherModel
    // this.model = options.model
}
```

But you shoul not mix models in a view, just have another view for the projectModel and use them both when needed

```
// something like
var countryView = new CountryView({model: myModel});
var projectView = new ProjectView({model: anotherModel});
```

and render them together from the router

Comment: I'm using my model as a dependency because I need to bring in data and logic from the model into my view. I was under the impression that was the way to do it??

Comment: You should definitely read this two http://backbonejs.org/#View-rendering , http://backbonejs.org/#Model-View-separation and a tutorial from this list https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites . My tutorial of choice was https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites#user-content-wine-cellar-app-by-christophe-coenraets , somewhere on youtube there is a video of it.

Answer (score 3):

In your view you can instantiate models other than the one which is referenced at `this.model`. E.g:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.countriesModel = new CountriesModel();

        // Anywhere in your view do stuff with `this.countriesModel`. E.g:
        // this.listenTo(this.countriesModel, ...)
        // this.countriesModel.fetch()
        // etc
    }

});
```

Comment: I've been able to call the array on the view with `this.countriesModel.countries`, but for some reason the function doesn't work with the following: `this.countriesModel.returnCode(4)`. I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.countriesModel.returnCode is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: @realph I'm not familiar with coffee script but if you had a function by that name in your model it would work, best bet is so write `debugger;` above the exception line and in Chrome with the inspector open run it, then in your console log inspect what is inside `this.countriesModel`

Comment: Weird. I can't work out what the debugger is doing, either. I can successfully return an array, but not an object – it's returned as `undefined`. I also can't return a function, it just tells me it's not a function. So frustrating.